# How to search for integer in a row at SqlDatabase with rawQuery?

Tags: android, mysql

here is my code:

```
    public String getFriendName(int aFindexnum){
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM peopleTable WHERE "+KEY_CBINDEX+"="+aFindexnum;
                Cursor cursor = ourDatabase2.rawQuery(sql, null);
                String Fname = cursor.getString(1);
                cursor.close();
                return Fname;
}
```

I am trying to search for an integer and than return other Value that is String in my sqldatabase
So i am passing in that aFindexnum which is the integer value in the Db and i want to find it
my problem was when i tried to do something like that:

```
        public String getFriendName(int aFindexnum){
            String aFindex = getString(aFindexnum);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM peopleTable WHERE "+KEY_CBINDEX+"=?";
            Cursor cursor = ourDatabase2.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {aFindex});
            String Fname = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.close();
            return Fname;
}
```

> ```
>       String aFindex = getString(aFindexnum); <<if i will turn this with
> ```
>
> parse into String will it work ?

```
public long createEntry( String name, String phonenum ,int phoneindex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_PHONENUM, phonenum);
    cv.put(KEY_CBINDEX, phoneindex);
    return ourDatabase2.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

this is the entry of the sql Db, so u can see in the third column i am putting an int and i want to search for it and get the name and the phone.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `getString()` in an activity gets a string from resources. Referring to a resource id with the name of an index number looks suspicious. If I understood your code and question, this

   ```
   Cursor cursor = ourDatabase2.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {aFindex});
   ```

   should be

   ```
   Cursor cursor = ourDatabase2.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { String.valueOf(aFindexnum) });
   ```

   and you can remove the first problematic `getString()`.
2. When you query and get a `Cursor`, you'll have to move it to a valid row before accessing column data. Add

   ```
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { ... }
   ```

Comment: Thanks mate, working great!
  `public String getFriendName(int aFindexnum){
   //String aFindex = getString(aFindexnum);
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM ContactsTable WHERE "+KEY_CBINDEX+"=?";
   Cursor cursor2 = ourDatabase2.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { String.valueOf(aFindexnum)});
   cursor2.moveToFirst();
   String Fname = cursor2.getString(1);
   cursor2.close();
   return Fname;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code and question,

By reading your sql String code you want row which matches `KEY_CBINDEX` value

If in your database data type of `KEY_CBINDEX` column is `int` then you can get `integer` value

By replacing

```
cursor.getString(1);
```

with

```
int intValue = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CBINDEX));
```

or if is string, then replace with

```
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CBINDEX)));
```

You have to replace it in your second code block.